# Where can I find a first course in representation theory with video lectures and assignments?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

I am a person who is self-studying math before applying for PhD positions. In my university, there was no course in Representation Theory during Bachelors or Masters.

> So, can you suggest a Master's Level online (i.e having videos of lectures available online) first course in Representation Theory (which also has a good number of assignments in PDF form or in between the videos).

There are online lectures in PDF form on OCW MIT, but I learn more from video lectures. That's why I thought of asking here.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question more suitable for Mathoverflow or Mathstackexchange?

Comment: Given that you are asking about maths that is not research level, I'd say your question is in the right place. If you were asking for literature on open problems or stuff that is not included in textbooks, then maybe MathOverflow would be better for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj51AM_VmB0VygPIzcUCH_jUG) introducing Representation Theory on YouTube by Fields medallist Richard E. Borcherds. It isn't a formal lecture course so far as I am aware, but I would suggest using a combination of sources to learn from since I don't think it is very common to find a full collection of video lectures together with accompanying assignments and lecture notes all freely available online.

There is also a third year course [Introduction to Representation Theory](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=104) at the University of Oxford with lecture notes and assignments (this will likely be similar in difficulty to Masters level courses at less prestigious universities).